# How to update Bittorrent Sync ARM on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian

I have Bittorrent Sync ARM version on my B+ right now and I'm getting a notice about a new version. Every tutorial I'm finding is not helping because btsync isn't letting me sudo service btsync stop. In fact, it doesn't show up on the service list at all.

I'm hesitant to try to replace the btsync file if the program is running (it actively syncs so it *must* be running) because I don't want to spend the time syncing everything again. Is it safe to just rename the old program and drop the new one in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming a file normally won't interfere with running but it will only use the new file on reboot.

It should take no bandwidth and less than a minute to synchronize all your files if they have already been copied. (assuming it stores the hashed state like normal bittorrent, or uses rsync tricks)

WARNING: Bittorrent Sync is not open source and not fully distributed so it may become unusable in the future. There are more flexible options (rsync, git-annex, etc).

(rsync will verify/sync 15TB in under a minute on a raspberrypi)

If Bittorrent Sync is running you will see it in `ps ax | grep -i sync` and you can safely ask it to stop with `kill $PID` (or if it won't stop, you can use `kill -9 $PID` to force stop it).

It may not have been installed with it's own service but instead might be in `grep -i sync /etc/init.d/rc.local` or `crontab -l | grep -i sync` or other less savory places.

It's good practice to keep an install.log on servers to let future admins know what (and how) was changed from the default distribution.